# java.lang.SecurityException: adb clearing user data is forbidden.'; Code: '1'

Tags: android, selenium, appium, appium-android

I'm hitting this error:

`java.lang.SecurityException: adb clearing user data is forbidden.'; Code: '1'`

while running the below mentioned code on `appium` server in `android 8.1.0 (oreo)` but the same code is running fine in `android 5.1 (lollipop)`. USB debugging is already on in mobile. Anyone having any idea why I'm hitting this error?`

```
package appium;
@BeforeTest

        public void setcapbilities() throws Exception
{

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("deviceName","Vipul");
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION,"8.1");
    cap.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    cap.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.calculator2");
    cap.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void  firstt()
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("7")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@AfterTest
public void kill()
{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Which device are you running this on?

Answer (score 0):

There few pointers which you can try to solve the issue you're facing.

First, use latest stable Appium server and Java client available.

Second, use `AndroidDriver <MobileElement>` instead of `RemoteWebDriver`. Since, AndroidDriver extends RemoteWebDriver via AppiumDriver, it must have overiden the `quit` method functionality.

Third, you don't need to call implicit wait everywhere. You must call it once in your set up method.

Forth, update your Android SDK and tools to latest.

Answer (score 0):

It is not neccessary that if a something works in **andorid v5** , then it should also work on **android v8**

**Reason**

To make the devices more secure , latest android versions are imposing restrictions on some already working APIs.

e.g. You can enable airplane mode using Appium API in mobile devices till **Android V6**, from **Android V7** onwards this API has been blocked.

**Solution**

looking at your code, it seems ,the session should get created successfully , the only thing u need to take care is how to make your test successfull. May be you need to change your Xpath as per the UI for Android V8.

did you try checking this Xpath in APPIUM Desktop ?

https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/12/31/appium-desktop-for-locating-elements/